# add class for parent element in jquery

Tags: jquery, parent

I have some li tags and within each li tags input tag of type radio is there.
Like

```
<li><input type='radio' value='cool' name='radiooption' id='2'>2</li>
<li ><input type='radio' name='radiooption' value='cool1' id='3'>3</li>
<li><input type='radio' value='cool' name='radiooption' checked="checked" id='4'>4</li>
<li><input type='radio' value='cool' name='radiooption' id='5'>5</li>
```

Now if I load the page containing the above code, then for the 3rd li one class will be added due to the corresponding radio button is already been selected.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[name='radiooption']").on("change", function() {
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .addClass("myClass")
        .siblings()
        .removeClass("myClass");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kEfkY/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
$(this).parent().addClass('class');
});
```

Btw you should change the id of the input you may get problems, so change it to like a1,a2,a3

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="radiooption"]').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) $(this).closest('li').addClass('myClass');
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope, there is no need in `toggleClass` here.

Comment: sorry to say to all. Please check my question, I have modified that.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the update. But its not working for me.Right now my code is looking like: <li><input type='radio' name='radiooption' id='2' value='2'  /><p>0-10</p></li><li><input type='radio' name='radiooption' id='3' value='3'  /><p>11-20</p></li><li><input type='radio' name='radiooption' id='4' value='4' checked='checked' /><p>21-40</p></li><li><input type='radio' style="" name='radiooption' id='5' value='5' checked='checked' /><p>41-50</p></li><li><input type='radio' name='radiooption' id='6' value='6'  /><p>51+</p></li> through browser view source.

Comment: @Sri - Then something else is wrong, as it works for me, see [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/2/) ??